# Yii URL rules to use ID as a parameter

Tags: yii2

In Yii I am using below code to generate a URL

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/delete',array('id' => 100))
```

It generates the URL like below and parameter ID is missing in the URL

```
http://localhost/yii-basic/web/index.php?r=site%2Fdelete
```

In the config file, rules are as below

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
       'post/<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>'=>'post/view',
        'posts/<tag:.*?>'=>'post/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#createUrl()-detail), the correct syntax would be:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(array('site/delete', 'id' => 100));
```

I find it more convinient  to use `\yii\helpers\Url` class and short array syntax:

```
Url::to(['site/delete', 'id' => 100]);
```